How to force make to always execute a target
Here below is a Makefile to generate PDF from asciidoc. The cover is an SVG image I modify at build time to inject year, revision, and resize some elements depending on the length of the title.
SHELL := /bin/bash

.DEFAULT_GOAL := all

# document revision
REV := "0.1.$(or $(shell git rev-parse HEAD), 0)"

# source directory
SRCDIR := ${CURDIR}/src

# theme directory
THEMEDIR := ../theme

# images directory
IMGDIR := images

# source files
ADOC_FILES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.adoc)

# document cover
COVER_TEMPLATE := $(SRCDIR)/$(IMGDIR)/cover-template.svg
COVER := $(SRCDIR)/$(IMGDIR)/cover.svg

# output directories
OUTDIR := ${CURDIR}/build
HTML_OUTDIR := $(OUTDIR)/html
PDF_OUTDIR := $(OUTDIR)/pdf

# output files
BASENAME := $(shell basename `pwd`)-$(REV)
HTML_FILE := $(HTML_OUTDIR)/$(BASENAME).html
PDF_FILE := $(PDF_OUTDIR)/$(BASENAME).pdf

# custom attributes
APPNAME=MyApp

.PHONY: all html pdf clean $(COVER)

all: html pdf

html: $(HTML_FILE)

pdf: $(PDF_FILE)

clean:
    @rm -rf $(OUTDIR) && rm -f $(COVER)

$(HTML_OUTDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(PDF_OUTDIR):
    mkdir -p $@

$(COVER):
    echo; \
    WIDTH=$$(magick -font Verdana -pointsize 30 label:"Kippis" -format "%[w]" info:) && \
    YEAR=$$(date +%Y) && \
    sed "s/\$$WIDTH/$${WIDTH}/g; s/\$$YEAR/$${YEAR}/g; s/\$$REV/${REV}/g" \
    $(COVER_TEMPLATE) > $@

$(HTML_FILE): $(ADOC_FILES) | $(HTML_OUTDIR)
    bundle exec asciidoctor \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -a revnumber=$(REV) \
        -a appname=$(APPNAME) \
        -a imagesdir=$(IMGDIR) \
        $(SRCDIR)/main.adoc \
        -o $@

$(PDF_FILE): $(COVER) $(ADOC_FILES) | $(PDF_OUTDIR)
    bundle exec asciidoctor-pdf \
        -r asciidoctor-diagram \
        -a notitle \
        -a revnumber=$(REV) \
        -a appname=$(APPNAME) \
        -a imagesdir=$(IMGDIR) \
        -a pdf-themesdir=$(THEMEDIR) \
        -a pdf-fontsdir="$(THEMEDIR);GEM_FONTS_DIR" \
        -a pdf-theme=custom \
        $(SRCDIR)/main.adoc \
        -o $@

Target $(PDF_FILE) depends on $(COVER) to update the document cover... problem is that target $(COVER) gets never executed, unless I add the echo command. By the way, I'd like to run $(COVER) always (.FORCE has no effect here), regardless of any change. Am I missing something?

If you want $(COVER) to always rebuild, then make it phony with .PHONY: $(COVER).  See the GNU Make manual for info on .PHONY.

I already tried with .PHONY, but it doesn't work. It only works when I add echo as the first command to the $(COVER target.

Using .PHONY will definitely force $(COVER) to always rebuild, if used correctly.  There's also no way that adding echo will change when the target is built or not.  I think there's something much more basic wrong here.  It would help if, instead of just describing an abstract problem you showed (cut + paste) the exact make command line you invoked and the results you got, and then described what you wanted to happen instead.  Also, trying to reproduce the behavior with a smaller, simpler makefile can often be illuminating.

As long as you are using .PHONY for other targets (and therefore depending on a make that supports it), there is no point in using an old-school .FORCE prerequisite for $(COVER).

Your recipe for $(COVER) does not appear to be wrong, but it is weird.  Why copy the template over the destination and then use sed -i, when you could instead just make sed read the original template directly, and redirect its output to the target?

Good point... just removed -i (this is something I left from my previous tries). And here's the exact make command: make pdf.

In the end I figured out that, even though VSCode displayed a tab, the first line of the `$(COVER) target had 4 spaces instead of a tab. Once replaced the 4 spaces with a tab, everything worked as expected.
